# openpyxl color cells based on value from another column

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

```
import pandas as pd 
from openpyxl import Workbook 
from pandas import ExcelWriter import openpyxl

wb = Workbook() 
sheet = wb.active 
writer = ExcelWriter('path\\test.xlsx')

list1 = [1,1,1,2,3,3,4,5]
list2 = [1,2,2,2,3,4,4,5]

comparison = [i == j for i,j in zip(list1,list2)]
comparison Out[76]: [True, False, False, True, True, False, True, True]

df = pd.DataFrame(list1,list2)

dataframe_spotovi.to_excel(writer,'Jazler spotovi') 
writer.save()
```

I would like to color rows in my 1st column based on their value - all the same values in one color (1,1,1 in red, then 2 in separate color, 3,3 in some other color, 4 in another color etc.).
I made the list2, so i can check if rows in list1 have same values (comparison).

I tried something like this:

```
for rows in sheet.iter_rows():
    for cell in rows:
        for a, b in zip(mirko, darko):
            if a == b:
                cell.fill = PatternFill(bgColor="FFC7CE", fill_type = "solid")
    else:
        color = 'FFBB00'
```

Nothing. I tried dataframe styler, but styler cannot iterate.

Any thoughts? Much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you might want to use conditional formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following creates a dataframe from some data, creates an `openpyxl` ExcelWriter. It then uses a colourmap from Matplotlib to give you a range of colours. For each unique value it assigns the next value from the colormap, starting with red:

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np

data = [
    [1, 'test', 1],
    [1, 'test', 2],
    [1, 'test', 3],
    [2, 'test', 4],
    [3, 'test', 5],
    [3, 'test', 6],
    [4, 'test', 7],
    [5, 'test', 8]]

write_path = "output.xlsx"
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["value", "comment", "index"])
unique = np.unique(df['value']).shape[0] + 1

with pd.ExcelWriter(write_path) as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet1", index=False)

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(write_path)
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name("Sheet1")   

# Create a color map
tohex = lambda r,g,b,a: '%02X%02X%02X%02X' % (a,r,g,b)
gist_rainbow = cm.gist_rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, unique))
gist_rainbow = np.array(gist_rainbow * 255, dtype=int)
gist_rainbow = iter([tohex(*gist_rainbow[i,:]) for i in range(unique)])
colours = {}
next_colour = next(gist_rainbow)    # get the next colour in the colormap

for cells in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2, min_col=1, max_col=1):
    cell = cells[0]

    try:
        colour = colours[cell.value]
    except KeyError:
        colours[cell.value] = next_colour
        colour = next_colour
        next_colour = next(gist_rainbow)    # get the next colour in the colormap

    cell.fill = PatternFill(start_color=colour, end_color=colour, fill_type='solid')

wb.save(write_path)
```

This would give you an Excel spreadsheet something looking like:

[image: Example Excel output]

Comment: thank You very much, this is exactly what I was trying to get. Alas, when applying to my project I get:   `next_colour = next(tab20c)     StopIteration`

Comment: It means you have more unique values than were in that colourmap. It now calculates the number of unique values and uses a continuous colour map.

Comment: thank you for helping out. when c/p your code to notebook or ide, i am getting this

Comment: You are welcome!  Don't forget to click on the grey tick under the up/down buttons to accept the answer as the accepted solution.

Comment: `TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-9c43ddc12e08> in <module>()
     18 write_path = "output.xlsx"
     19 df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["value", "comment", "index"])
---> 20 unique = len(np.unique(df))
     21 
     22 with pd.ExcelWriter(write_path) as writer:`

Comment: `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\arraysetops.py in unique(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts, axis)
    208     ar = np.asanyarray(ar)
    209     if axis is None:
--> 210         return _unique1d(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts)
    211     if not (-ar.ndim <= axis < ar.ndim):
    212         raise ValueError('Invalid axis kwarg specified for unique')`

Comment: `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\arraysetops.py in _unique1d(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts)
    275         aux = ar[perm]
    276     else:
--> 277         ar.sort()
    278         aux = ar
    279     flag = np.concatenate(([True], aux[1:] != aux[:-1]))

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`

Comment: and when i apply it to my project, something different, i do not understand it at all `line 74, in <module>
    for cells in ws.iter_rows(min_col=1, max_col=1):

TypeError: iter_rows() got an unexpected keyword argument 'min_col'`

Comment: Try now, it should only have calculated unique values for the first column.

Comment: You might also want to make sure your `openpyxl` package is up to date `pip install openpyxl --upgrade`. e.g. `2.4.9`

Comment: that is it thanks a lot! i had to upgrade pyopenxl to latest version.